# How to create a variable that is the sum of consecutive rows within a given time frame and by id

Tags: r, group-by, sum, rolling-computation, runner

I am trying to implement a sum of consecutive values that fall with 365 days of each other, grouped by a unique identifier in R. For example, for date 1 of a particular ID, we would add dates 2,3,4 (fall within 365 days) of the same ID to get a total cost for date 1. Then for date 2, we would add 3 and 4 to get that total cost and so on. I have tried several rolling sums ([R dplyr rolling sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153835/r-dplyr-rolling-sum)) and similar solutions from dplyr that take sum consecutive values ([Calculate sum of a column if the difference between consecutive rows meets a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928394/calculate-sum-of-a-column-if-the-difference-between-consecutive-rows-meets-a-con)) with certain constraints but could not get the code to distinguish the amount of days. I have included a sample dataset with a solution dataset for an example that I am looking for.

Starting Data Set

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
admitdt <-c("2014-10-19","2014-10-24","2015-01-31","2016-01-20","2017-06-30","2017-07-17","2015-04-21","2015-04-22","2015-05-04","2015-07-25","2014-11-11")
cost<-c(2000,14077,5000,200,560,5000,888,5959,1819,7508,6406)
cost365<-c(21077,19077,5200,200,5560,5000,16174,15286,9327,7508,6406)
df2<-data.frame(ID,admitdt,cost,cost365)

  ID    admitdt  cost
1   1 2014-10-19  2000
2   1 2014-10-24 14077
3   1 2015-01-31  5000
4   1 2016-01-20   200
5   1 2017-06-30   560
6   1 2017-07-17  5000
7   2 2015-04-21   888
8   2 2015-04-22  5959
9   2 2015-05-04  1819
10  2 2015-07-25  7508
11  3 2014-11-11  6406
```

Solution:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
admitdt <-c("2014-10-19","2014-10-24","2015-01-31","2016-01-20","2017-06-30","2017-07-17","2015-04-21","2015-04-22","2015-05-04","2015-07-25","2014-11-11")
cost<-c(2000,14077,5000,200,560,500,888,5959,1819,7508,6406)
cost365<-c(21077,19077,5200,200,5560,5000,16174,15286,9327,7508,6406)
df2<-data.frame(ID,admitdt,cost,cost365)
  ID    admitdt  cost cost365
1   1 2014-10-19  2000   21077
2   1 2014-10-24 14077   19077
3   1 2015-01-31  5000    5200
4   1 2016-01-20   200     200
5   1 2017-06-30   560    5560
6   1 2017-07-17  5000    5000
7   2 2015-04-21   888   16174
8   2 2015-04-22  5959   15286
9   2 2015-05-04  1819    9327
10  2 2015-07-25  7508    7508
11  3 2014-11-11  6406    6406
```

Comment: How many rows are there in the real data?

Comment: @IanCampbell , There are around one hundred thousand rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `purrr::map`:

```
library(dplyr); library(purrr)
df2 %>%
  mutate(admitdt = as.Date(admitdt)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(cost365 = map_dbl(admitdt,~sum(cost[(.x - admitdt) <= 0 &
                                             (.x - admitdt) >= -365])))
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID admitdt     cost cost365
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 2014-10-19  2000   21077
 2     1 2014-10-24 14077   19077
 3     1 2015-01-31  5000    5200
 4     1 2016-01-20   200     200
 5     1 2017-06-30   560    1060
 6     1 2017-07-17   500     500
 7     2 2015-04-21   888   16174
 8     2 2015-04-22  5959   15286
 9     2 2015-05-04  1819    9327
10     2 2015-07-25  7508    7508
11     3 2014-11-11  6406    6406
```

Comment: In Ian Campbell we trust.

Comment: nice approach @Ian, +1

Answer (score 3):

I am giving 2 methods each in `slider` and `runner`.  Out of these I like `slider` because of its clarity of syntax.  Neverthess, the strategy in both are nearly same,

- `date` column will act as `index` in both.
- slider gives more control becuase it has `.before` and `.after` agruments, which in the instant case you need only `after = days(365)` (that is integrated with lubridate)
- in runner k is always backwards so I used `-364` there.
- Rest is clear.  Still If any further clarification is needed, do ask.

In `slider` you can do

```r
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
admitdt <-c("2014-10-19","2014-10-24","2015-01-31","2016-01-20","2017-06-30","2017-07-17","2015-04-21","2015-04-22","2015-05-04","2015-07-25","2014-11-11")
cost<-c(2000,14077,5000,200,560,5000,888,5959,1819,7508,6406)
cost365<-c(21077,19077,5200,200,5560,5000,16174,15286,9327,7508,6406)
df<-data.frame(ID,admitdt,cost)

df
#>    ID    admitdt  cost
#> 1   1 2014-10-19  2000
#> 2   1 2014-10-24 14077
#> 3   1 2015-01-31  5000
#> 4   1 2016-01-20   200
#> 5   1 2017-06-30   560
#> 6   1 2017-07-17  5000
#> 7   2 2015-04-21   888
#> 8   2 2015-04-22  5959
#> 9   2 2015-05-04  1819
#> 10  2 2015-07-25  7508
#> 11  3 2014-11-11  6406

library(slider)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(admitdt = as.Date(admitdt),
              cost365 = slider::slide_index_sum(x = cost,
                                                i = admitdt,
                                                after = days(365)))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>       ID admitdt     cost cost365
#>    <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 2014-10-19  2000   21077
#>  2     1 2014-10-24 14077   19077
#>  3     1 2015-01-31  5000    5200
#>  4     1 2016-01-20   200     200
#>  5     1 2017-06-30   560    5560
#>  6     1 2017-07-17  5000    5000
#>  7     2 2015-04-21   888   16174
#>  8     2 2015-04-22  5959   15286
#>  9     2 2015-05-04  1819    9327
#> 10     2 2015-07-25  7508    7508
#> 11     3 2014-11-11  6406    6406
```

---

Or in `runner`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
admitdt <-c("2014-10-19","2014-10-24","2015-01-31","2016-01-20","2017-06-30","2017-07-17","2015-04-21","2015-04-22","2015-05-04","2015-07-25","2014-11-11")
cost<-c(2000,14077,5000,200,560,5000,888,5959,1819,7508,6406)
cost365<-c(21077,19077,5200,200,5560,5000,16174,15286,9327,7508,6406)
df<-data.frame(ID,admitdt,cost)

library(runner)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(admitdt = as.Date(admitdt),
         cost365 = runner::sum_run(x = cost,
                                   idx = admitdt,
                                   k = 365,
                                   lag = -364))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>       ID admitdt     cost cost365
#>    <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 2014-10-19  2000   21077
#>  2     1 2014-10-24 14077   19077
#>  3     1 2015-01-31  5000    5200
#>  4     1 2016-01-20   200     200
#>  5     1 2017-06-30   560    5560
#>  6     1 2017-07-17  5000    5000
#>  7     2 2015-04-21   888   16174
#>  8     2 2015-04-22  5959   15286
#>  9     2 2015-05-04  1819    9327
#> 10     2 2015-07-25  7508    7508
#> 11     3 2014-11-11  6406    6406
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

df2 %>%
  mutate(rolls = map2(ymd(admitdt), ID, ~ df2 %>%
                        filter(ID == .y & ymd(admitdt) %within% interval(.x, .x + 365)) %>%
                        pull(cost) %>%
                        reduce(`+`)))

   ID    admitdt  cost cost365 rolls
1   1 2014-10-19  2000   21077 21077
2   1 2014-10-24 14077   19077 19077
3   1 2015-01-31  5000    5200  5200
4   1 2016-01-20   200     200   200
5   1 2017-06-30   560    5560  5560
6   1 2017-07-17  5000    5000  5000
7   2 2015-04-21   888   16174 16174
8   2 2015-04-22  5959   15286 15286
9   2 2015-05-04  1819    9327  9327
10  2 2015-07-25  7508    7508  7508
11  3 2014-11-11  6406    6406  6406
```

Or in **base R**:

```
df2$rolls <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  df2 <- transform(df2, admitdt = as.Date(admitdt, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
  tmp <- subset(df2, ID == x & admitdt >= y & admitdt <= y + 365)
  sum(tmp$cost)
}, df2$ID, as.Date(df2$admitdt, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```